# TcpClient: How do I close and reconnect it again?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Hello and thanks for your help.
This time I would like to ask about TcpClient. 
I have a server program and I am writing a client program.
This client uses TcpClient. It starts by creating a new client

```
clientSocket=new TcpClient();
```

(By the way, can this cause exceptions? just in case I put it inside a try-catch but I am not sure if that is really necessary)
Anyway, later I enter a loop and inside this loop I connect to the server

```
clientSocket.Connect("xx.xx.xx.xx",port);
```

Then I create a NetworkStream with

```
clientStream=clientSocket.GetStream();
```

and then start waiting for data from the server through Read. I know this is blocking so I also set a ReadTimeOut (say 1 second)

Anyway, so far so good. 
Later if I don't receive anything from the server, I attempt to send something to it. If this keeps happening for say 3 times I **want to close the connection and reconnect to the server again**

(notice that a whole different problem is when the server somehow is down, cause that causes other kinds of errors in the client-perhaps I will ask about that later)

So, what do I do?

```
 if(clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Closing the socket");
                clientSocket.Close();
            }
```

I close the socket. 
The loop is finished so I go again to the beginning and try to connect to the server.

```
clientSocket.Connect("xx.xx.xx.xx",port);
```

However this causes an error(an unhandled exception actually) "Can not access a disposed object"

So **my question is**  *How can I close and reconnect to the server again??*

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Thanks. I added a tag. Is that ok?  (by the way how do I put new lines in the comments... If I press enter it just add the comment. tried ctrl-enter, shift-enter , does not work...

Comment: Yes, that's great. Thanks! Comments do not support paragraphs or carriage returns. They're always a single block of text. They're comments, not paragraphs. :-) There should rarely (if ever) be a need for a comment long enough to require multiple paragraphs.

Comment: You should only put code in a `try`/`catch` block when you know explicitly which exception you are catching and that you can meaningfully handle it. It is an anti-pattern to just catch exceptions. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `TcpClient` instance can only be used to connect once. You can simply instantiate a new `TcpClient`, rather than trying to re-open a closed one.

Comment: Thank you. Is this so?  So I must instantiate a new one....  In some code in C++ I have they use sockets and they simply "create" a new socket (they are using asynchronous) . But in TcpClient there is no "create" so I suppose just a new should be used right?                            By the way I have another related question and I will post it after I fix this problem. Will appreciate your help on that one too :)

Comment: By the way, can instantiating a new TcpClient provoke exceptions?                  Should I put it inside a try-catch?

Comment: It seems it is working :) By the way, when I close the TcpClient, I suppose that all resources are disposed? or maybe the garbage collector gets it? I don't want to be leaving things out every time a new iteration of instantiation is performed.....

Comment: I don't *think* the constructor can throw an exception. `TcpClient` implements `IDisposable`, which means that when you call `Dispose` on it, it will clean up after itself. The convention for using `IDisposable` is to use a `using` statement. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: _"I don't think the constructor can throw an exception"_ -- **incorrect**. The constructor certainly can throw an exception. `TcpClient` creates its underlying `Socket` object during construction, and the [`Socket` constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,926144127569a5c2) throws a `SocketException` if the native socket object fails to be created.

Comment: You're right, decompiling the `TcpClient` noargs constructor shows that it does involve instantiating a socket with `new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);` which could throw `SocketException`.

Answer (score 11):

As explained in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39402050), a `TcpClient` object can only be connected once. If you want to reconnect to the server, you have to create a new `TcpClient` object and call `Connect()` again.

That said, you have a number of apparent misconceptions in your question:

1. First and most important, you should not use `ReceiveTimeout` if you have any intention whatsoever of trying to use the `TcpClient` object again, e.g. to send some data to the server. Once the timeout period has expired, the underlying socket is no longer usable.
   If you want to periodically send data to the server when the server hasn't sent data to you, you should use asynchronous I/O (which you should do anyway, in spite of the learning curve) and use a regular timer object to keep track of how long it's been since you received data from the server.
2. The `TcpClient` constructor certainly can throw an exception. At the very least, *any* attempt to `new` a reference type object could throw `OutOfMemoryException`, and in the case of `TcpClient`, it ultimately tries to create a native socket handle, which could also fail.
   While all I/O objects and methods can throw exceptions, you should only ever catch exceptions that you have a way to handle gracefully. So before you add a `try`/`catch` block to your code, decide what it is you want to do in the case of an exception that will ensure that your code doesn't corrupt any data and continues to operate correctly. It is generally not possible to gracefully handle `OutOfMemoryException` (and impractical to protect all uses of `new` in any case), but you certainly can catch `SocketException`, which could be thrown by the constructor. If that exception is thrown, you should immediately abandon the attempt to create and use `TcpClient`, and report the error the user so that they can attempt to correct whatever problem prevented the socket's creation.
3. If your server is expected to be sending you data, and you don't receive it, then closing the connection and retrying is unlikely to improve the situation. That will only cause additional load on the server, making it even more likely it will fail to respond. Likewise sending the same data over and over. You should your request *once*, wait as long as is practical for a response from the server, and if you get no response within the desired time, report the error to the user and let them decide what to do next.
   Note that in this case, you *could* use the `ReceiveTimeout` property, because all you're going to do if you don't get a response in time is abandon the connection, which is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I suppose you are talking about the ReadTimeout property?

Comment: @KansaiRobot: the relevant property on `TcpClient` is `ReceiveTimeout`. But yes, this is equivalent to `NetworkStream.ReadTimeout`. Both ultimately just call `Socket.SetSocketOption()` with `SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout`.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I would disagree with you on 3. TCP connections can and do break... the server might restart, there might be a network glitch anywhere from Azure to your ISP to your local network. Otherwise this is a great answer, thanks for it

Answer (score 7):

Very simple:

```
client.Close();
client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(host, port);
```